# Adding a drive to a hardware RAID-0 array

Tags: raid-0, hardware-raid

I'm building a RAID-0 array as my main boot "drive" and was wondering how adding disks to the array works in implementation. I'll be using either the Intel [RT3WB080](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816117214) or the Intel [RS2BL080](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816117152), which are effectively the same with varying cache sizes (256MB vs 512MB).

I'd like to start the array of SSDs with either 2 or 3 drives, eventually expanding up to four in time. How does this work? Do I have to completely start from scratch after I add each drive, or is there a utility in the Intel cards which will redistribute and restripe the data across the new amount of drives? I understand that I'd have to expand the actual partition(s) and that's totally acceptable for me as I can take the drives offline and do that using GParted or a similar tool.

Is it possible to add physical disks to an Intel hardware RAID-0 array without completely wiping the array each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the RAID card. Technically it is possible, but it is not entirely trivial and even if a card supports it I would create and test a backup before any attempt.

And if you already have a backup then wiping the existing array and restoring from that backup is likely faster.

So, technically the answer is: Yes, it is possible.
But in practical terms it is: No, do not do it.

Comment: Just found it in the manual and it said pretty much exactly what you did: `Please make a backup before attempting to add devices to an array.`. Well done.

Comment: That's kind of silly. If you care about the contents, you'd have a backup anyway. RAID is not backup, especially RAID 0 which actually increases the chance of data loss.

Comment: It makes sense from the manuals writer point of view.